# Using htaccess to dynamically generate webpages

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm building a website that is similar to Yelp: a database of businesses of which the user can view details. I'm trying to mimic the same URL structure of Yelp, for example:

http://www.yelp.com/biz/business-name-webpage

How do I dynamically generate business page URLs as such, instead of needing a separate .html/.php file for every single business in my database?

Answer (score 0):

Those dynamically generated URLs are called clean URL and people use them for different reasons like SEO. If you have [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) enabled, then you can use the code below. It passes requests for non-existing files or directories to `route.php`. Then you can generate your output based on given path and send it to user.
.htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) route.php?path=$1 [L]
```

route.php

```
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['path'])){
    echo 'Path is not set!';
}else{
    //Print content for $_GET['path']
}
?>
```